# Creating a binary varible using percentages

Tags: r, binary, conditional-statements

I am working on the voter turnout in the 2015 UK General Election using constituency level voting data from the 2010 election.

Here the question I am struggling to answer:

Using the "majority" measure for the 2010 election, create a variable named "marginal" equal to 1 if the "majority" measure in 2010 was less than or equal to 10% and 0 otherwise.

I don't know how to include this condition in my ifelse function. Do I have to use something else?

Comment: Could you provide some data and the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

```
marginal <- majority<=quantile(majority, probs=0.1)
```

I am not sure what you really want because I dont have the data, maybe you need this one